# Trying to convert a value from a time input into a unix timestamp in Javascript

Tags: javascript, unix, time

I have a time input

```
<input type="time" id="end_time" name="end_time" value="12:30">
```

What I wan to do is compare the current time with the value of this input. However, I have tow problems the javascript method I am using prints out the time as a unix timestamp.

```
menu_time = new Date().getTime();
```

How do I convert the `end_time` value with the `menu_time` value in order to compare them?

```
end_time = $('#end_time').val();
if($(menu_time) > $(end_time)){
    console.log('true');
}else{
     console.log('false');
 }
```

Comment: Need a lot more details here. Do you want to use the user's current timezone, or a particular timezone? Is the time in the input field always a particular format? (You've used the `time` type, which [does have a well-defined format](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.time.html#input.time.attrs.value) but [doesn't have good browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime) so that format can't be relied on.) Is the time in the input field interpreted to be "today" (according to the user's clock), or the next future instance of that time, or the next past instance?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the end_time to timestamp as well in order in order to compare with menu_time.

```
end_time = Date.parse($('#end_time').val());

if($(menu_time) > $(end_time)){
    console.log('true');
}else{
     console.log('false');
 }
```

Comment: You're missing an open parenthesis at `Date.parse`. Also, `Date.parse('12:30')` yields `NaN`.

Comment: My bad, thanks! Guess it wouldn't be easy to compare unless the end_time also contain the complete Date.